# How to escape special characters while using lsearch?

Tags: tcl

How to escape special characters(e.g "[]") while using search?

Consider the following scenario:

```
>> set L { a b c [] }
>> a b c []
>> lsearch $L b
>> 1
>> lsearch $L "[]"
>> -1
```

I'm looking to get 3 when I run lsearch $L "[]"

Answer (score 1):

When looking for fixed strings rather than patterns, it is easiest to use the -exact option to lsearch. You also need to make sure Tcl doesn't do substitution on the search string, for example by enclosing it inside curly braces. Otherwise you'll tell Tcl to look for an empty string (the result of executing an empty command string):

```
lsearch -exact $L {[]}
```

Comment: Newbie here. Thanks a lot!